# Postgres Large table Optimal index selection for Select Query With In Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

We have a very large table with a total number of rows around `~4 billion` and everyday throughput is around `~20-25 million`.

Below is the Sample Table definition.

```
table_name (
   id bigint,
   user_id bigint,
   status  smallint,
   date    timestamp,
   .
   .
   some more columns
);
```

> NOTE: ***status*** is an enum and can have 6-7 possible values.

Below is the query that we want to optimise:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE user_id = $user_id 
AND status in (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10) 
ORDER BY date 
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Initially, we were having `index1` on `table_name (user_id, status)`.

Since this index was not giving optimal performance. We thought of including the date in the index as well.

Now, we have tried creating a bunch of different indexes on the table, but the explain plan always picks up the initial index i.e: ***index1***.

Below are the ***indexes*** that we tried:

```
index2: table_name (user_id, status, date)
index3: table_name (user_id, status, date) where (status = ANY (ARRAY [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]))
index4: table_name (user_id, status) where (status = ANY (ARRAY [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]));
```

Below is the explain analyse output:

```
Limit  (cost=27029.07..27029.12 rows=20 width=251) (actual time=32.466..32.470 rows=20 loops=1)
 ->  Sort  (cost=27029.07..27049.17 rows=8041 width=251) (actual time=32.465..32.467 rows=20 loops=1)
      Sort Key: id DESC
      Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 38kB
    ->  Index Scan using index1 on table_name wt  (cost=0.58..26815.10 rows=8041 width=251) (actual time=0.027..26.991 rows=37362 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((user_id = 111111) AND (status = ANY ('{1,3,2,7,6,10,8}'::integer[])))

Planning Time: 0.320 ms
Execution Time: 32.498 ms
```

Our database ***postgres*** version is: `12.7` and we run `vaccuming` regularly.

We want to understand why other ***indexes*** are not being used for our ***query***.

Also given our use case, Can there be a better way of creating ***index*** so that we can serve the ***query*** in acceptable response time?

Comment: 1) A less specific index is redundant and therefore I would delete it (index2 should be sufficient) 2) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/planner-stats.html

Comment: 32 milliseconds seems quite OK - how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :- when we run the query for the first time for a user it takes almost 25-30 seconds, the explain analyse plan I have shared is for subsequent query. I am guessing after first page data page is loaded in memory and we are getting better results.

Comment: If you use `explain (analyze, buffers)` this would be visible in the plan

Comment: You need to capture the plan that is actually the problem.  You should be able to just pick a new user and show us the `explain (analyze, buffers)` for that one.

Comment: I am assuming the vast majority of rows were ruled out by the `user_id =` condition.  But how many more were ruled out by the `status in (...)` condition?

Comment: Is "id" a primary key?  It is not declared as such in your DDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX table_name_desc_index ON table_name (userid,_date DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Then try following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
inner join (values (1),(2),(3),(6),(7),(10)) val(v) ON (table_name.status = v )
WHERE user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY date
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark: this index is giving us better performance: table_name (user_id asc, date desc) after slightly updating the query and adding nulls last to order by clause.

Comment: @MohdWaseem, could you share new explain plan output?

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting `*`, so you will not be able to get an index-only scan due to the `*` dragging in more columns than are in the index.  The only advantage of those other indexes you showed (that I can see) would be to enable index-only scans, so if that cannot work, it is not surprising those indexes are not selected for use.  You could test this theory by changing the `*` to just the columns appearing in the index to see what happens.

About one of your indexes:

```
(user_id, status, date) where (status = ANY (ARRAY [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]))
```

This index seems rather pointless.  The benefit of the WHERE clause is that it reduces the disparate qualifying values of "status" down to a single value ('true').  But then putting "status" into the index body just breaks them back up again.  The better index would be:

```
(user_id, date) where (status = ANY (ARRAY [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]))
```

This one can jump to the end of the specific user_id, scan backwards (to fulfill the `order by date desc`) and stop once it finds 20 rows.  When you have "status" as an interloper, it prevents it from doing that.